# RFM69W transceiver - Poor range

Tags: arduino, rf, radio, transceiver

I'm having some difficulties with the RFM69W radio transceiver using Arduino Unos with the recommended RadioHead library. I have 2 Unos - each with one RFM69W - successfully sending and receiving messages, however I'm unable to get more than a few meters in range (open air).

All my research is coming up with the RFM69W being able to reach at least 100m, which I'm assuming requires tweaking of the configuration. The non high-powered (HW) version I'm using allows a max Tx power of +13. I've tried changing the data rate to the lowest possible - 2kbps @ 5kHz, which may have gained me an extra meter in open air. I've confirmed my wiring is correct against multiple schematics. I do not, however, have any sort of antenna connected to neither the trasmitting RFM69W nor the receiving.

Does anyone have experience tweaking these RFM69Ws to achieve the ranges I'm reading about everywhere? Would adding an antenna - even just a simple piece of wire - really improve my current few meters to 100+?

Comment: People add antennas only because they look cool, the really don't do anything...

Comment: Red one look particularly nice.

Comment: You don't have an antenna on them? Why not? Doesn't it need one? Check the datasheet and match the antenna with the required VSWR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFM69W apparently doesn't have an integrated antenna, which you definitely need to improve the range.

A wire antenna with the correct length would already improve the range for sure, however, I don't think that you can reach that 100m+ with it. There are different antenna types which could be used but connecting an antenna to an RF module is not as trivial as it sounds first. (Search for impedance matching)

Answer (score 0):

> I do not, however, have any sort of antenna connected to neither the
>   trasmitting RFM69W nor the receiving

Put an antenna on them - how can you expect decent distances without an antenna? Without a transmit antenna you might damage the transmitter because all that power has to go somewhere and it usually ends up overheating the output transistors.

Without a receive antenna you have noise and very little signal.